# Android Virtual Device freezing during its loading

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've downloaded Eclipse Classic 3.5 Galileo, the last version of Android SDK, downloaded and installed Eclipse Android 1.6 platform.
I've created first (and the only) AVD with Android 1.6 and the default skin.
The log may show more:
I've filtered only neccessary messages (warnings, errors).

-http://www.clipboard.cz/63c

As you can see, my new AVD has started in 16:17 and it was still loading in 17:35...
The emulator looks like this:

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/3540/androidloading.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/3540/androidloading.png)

PS: The restrictions about number of links for new accounts are REALLY annoying...

Comment: OT, but the restrictions effectively prevent bots from posting those nasty link lists. Get some reputation and you'll be fine! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433315/android-emulator-refuses-to-boot/7052598#7052598

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. It was always not responded when started, tried from eclipse, directly (windows vista home).

But it work if I set compatibility mode to windows xp service pack 2 and select to run as administrator.

Comment: it's funny, and also a little sad, how this was the solution

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Galileo running in Linux I lowered the version of the Android emulator. In the AVD config menu I lowered the Target to 1.5. I think the project Build target API level, entered when you create a project, needs to match the API level of your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the avd through the android tools gui. Helps for me sometimes...

Comment: I've created the avd at first through Eclipse icon - Android SDK and AVD Manager, which is perhaps what you mean... Now I've tried to create it using CommandLine - "android create avd -n MyNewAndroid -t 1"

But unfortunately it's acting identically... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've **reinstalled the whole system** (Windows Vista) and **now it's working**. Perhaps there was installed some bad software, which Eclipse, or sth from Android SDK do not like... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

All you got to do is while creating a Virtual Device, add a new hardware - 
"Device Ram Size" & set it to "512" or whatever is enough as per your requirement. Basically you have to reduce the RAM size so that your computer can provide it to the emulator. If you have already created one, you can do above steps in edit mode.