# Android emulator refuses to boot

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, boot-animation

I'm an Android newbie trying to learn how to port one of my apps to the Android platform. I've been following this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#overview

I'm stuck unable to boot up the emulator  :(  When I tell it to start, it would just stick at the "Android" boot animation for hours on end.  I searched online and found some pages talking about disabling the boot animation.  I did so and tried again.  There's no boot animation (just the word "Android" flashing), but it's still hours with no sign of booting.  'top' shows  an app called 'emulator' using a lot of CPU.

Am I doing something wrong?  My system is an AMD Athlon X2 dual-core QL-60, 1900 MHz with 3GB ram.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I had these issues before, same specs. Amd dual core 3gb ram. Honestly you're probably closing it too early. The first time takes a real long time compared to subsequent start ups. Just let it run until it starts. Give it at least 15 solid minutes before you give up. I would allow 30.

(I know I'm exaggerating here, but it really feels like I've waited that long before)

Oh, and once you start developing, don't reboot it unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Try emulator @myavd -no-boot-anim -show-kernel -shell and read the output.

Comment: Same here. I've let it load for hours, then recreated the AVD, then reinstalled the whole Android Studio 2, but it's still garbage. All I get is errors like this: "emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Invalid format in query 'listžM0·˘M0·¦M0·ŞM0·®M0..." and this "emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in ''"...

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem and fixed it by deleting the emulator and creating a new one.
In eclipse:

1. Menu Window -> Android SVK and AVD Manager
2. Select Virtual devices (should be selected already)
3. Select the emulator giving you problems
4. Click edit to see the setting and remember them, click cancel.
5. Click delete to delete the emulator.
6. CLick create to create a new one that is the same as the old one.
7. Click start.

It started in about 30 seconds after I did that.

Normally the emulator starts in about 2-3 minutes for me.  Then it mysteriously stopped working.  I was seeing boot animation for 30 minutes before I gave up.

- Note #1: Doing this will wipe your user data.
- Note #2: As mentioned else where, it's a good idea to check "Enabled" for the snapshot, this lets you do faster startup next time.
- Note #3: Also my new emulator came up in chinese.  That's kinda of weird :)

Comment: This worked for me. Didn't need to delete my old one though just made a new one.

Comment: Perfect advice, this solved the problem after I upgraded to use the x86 CPU/ABI and the emulator refused to boot (getting stuck at the Android animation).

Answer (score 3):

Android emulator release 9 has new "snapshot" feature. You can [save state of emulator](http://good-android-dev.blogspot.com/2011/02/slow-android-emulator-speed-up-it.html) (make image of emulator) and avoid booting when you start the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I see a similar problem while attempting to run applications on an emulator while the emulator isn't started yet. I find that starting the emulator manually via the "Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager" will load in just a couple minutes or faster, as expected. After the emulator is started manually in this way, you can load applications into it without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem on my laptop using I5 8GB RAM. The only solution that worked for me was connecting the laptop charger when launching the emulator. May sound wierd but this always works for me.